# Filter dataframe by variable and output as a table in shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, filtering

I'm stuck a little with Shiny output. I want to filter dataframe and output the results as a table. The dataframe is the long format of cases. The "variable" are the regions one I want to filter by :

```
> str(UZ_COVID19_long_rev0)
'data.frame':   1694 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date    : POSIXct, format: "2020-03-15" "2020-03-16" "2020-03-17" ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 14 levels "Karak_Rep","Andijon",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...


library(shiny)

tib<-UZ_COVID19_long_rev0

ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Selection Panel"),
    sidebarPanel(
        selectizeInput('region', 'Select region', 
                       choices = c(levels(tib$variable)))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("table")
    )
)

server = function(input, output, session) 
    {
    
    output$table <- renderTable({
        tib %>%
            filter(variable == input$region)
    })
        
    }
    
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But I receive an error: "object 'variable' not found"

I believe there is an error in the code, but can not get the one.

Comment: did you also run library(dplyr)?

Comment: I don;t. Do you think I can't run %>% code 'cos it requires dplyr?

Comment: It was easy solution.  :) Thank you.